# jQuery ON error. No error when using LIVE

Tags: jquery

This is my current, i want to change .live but .on is not working..

```
$('#SearchString').live('keydown',function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    if (!$("#SearchString").val()) {
        alert("Inget postnummer eller ort angiven!");
        return false;
    }
}
});




 $('#SearchString').on('keydown',function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    if (!$("#SearchString").val()) {
        alert("Inget postnummer eller ort angiven!");
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

This is the ON version

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? .on() was added in 1.7 http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: what is jquery file version

Comment: have you also upgraded jQuery version..?

Comment: please share the `on` version you tried

Comment: .live is aviable, in the version im using but.. Id rather not use it since im planning on upgrading to the newest. and .Live is removed then

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson still you're not sharing the version of jQuery?

Comment: it should be `$(document).on('keydown', '#SearchString', function(){...})`

Comment: Well, you didn't do the conversion correctly. Why don't you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/live/, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In event delegation model of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the target element selector is passed as the second argument to the `on()` method.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#SearchString', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        if (!$("#SearchString").val()) {
            alert("Inget postnummer eller ort angiven!");
            return false;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid that code does not work, and im using 1.9.0

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson can you share the associated html as well

Comment: nvm, i got it to work.. I missed something my bad.